# MySQL select snippet of text based on key words

Tags: mysql

I have a query pulling out search results based on relevance to the search term:

```
SELECT *, 
( (1.3 * (MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.6 * (MATCH(txtContent) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance 
FROM content 
WHERE (MATCH(strTitle,txtContent) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

I would also like to be able to pull out from the description the first instance of the search match. So if searching for "john smith" I'd like my results to display like:

> Page Title 1
>   ...snippet matching **john smith**...
>
> Page Title 2  ... snippet **john** matching....
>
> Page Title 3 .... snippet **smith** matching **john**...

etc etc

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with a case statement:

```
select *,
       ( (1.3 * (MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.6 * (MATCH(txtContent) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance,
      (case when MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) > 0
            then 'snippet matching +john+smith'
            . . .
       end)
```

Personally, I would put the matches as separate variables in a subquery:

```
select
from (select t.*,
             MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as match_join_smith,
             . . .
      from t
     ) t
```

And then use these variables for the logic in the outer query.